# Spring REST @RequestMapping extract incorrectly if value contains ‘#’

Tags: java, spring

See following Spring REST example, if a request such as “http://localhost:8080/site/name/exemple#name” is submitted, Spring returns “exemple“ and extract half and delete text after #.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/site")
public class SiteController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{myname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//myname='exemple'
    ...
    }
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: It's desired behaviour. What do you want to do with `#name`??

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn 
"exemple#name" is an exemple of a product name i want to search in my db and print. Exemple : http://localhost:4200/site?name=exemple%23name

Answer (score 3):

"#" is a reserved character in a URL. It must be escaped. It represents the beginning of the fragment portion of the URL. Thus, name is "exemple", and the fragment is "name".